# Use Google Maps in a Service

Tags: java, android, google-maps, service

All- I have a sports-tracker application in which I have a `service` running a stopwatch so the user's device can go to sleep and what-not with out the stopwatch stopping. I also want to include a `Map` tab in a my app so users can see where they've gone. I tried to use the main activity to accomplish this and it worked fine but every time the phone went to sleep, the main activity quit, pulling the maps down with it. This created gaps in the GPS and makes it impossible to track speed or distance. So I tried to put the map in my service but ran into problems such as my service has to extend `MapActivity` (but also has to extend `Service`). Here is what I have tried:

```
public class KeepGoing extends Service { //But also has to extend MapView?  
MapView mapView = null;
MapController mapController = null;
MyLocationOverlay whereAmI = null;

protected boolean isLocationDisplayed() {
    return whereAmI.isMyLocationEnabled();
}

protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}
```

Also:

```
    @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {      
    start();        
    return(START_NOT_STICKY);       
}   

private void start() {

    mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_START_TIMER);

    LayoutInflater inflater = ( LayoutInflater ) getSystemService( LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
    View layout = inflater.inflate( R.layout.activity_main , null );

    mapView = (MapView) layout.findViewById(R.id.mapview);  

    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    mapController = mapView.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(15);

    whereAmI = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
    mapView.getOverlays().add(whereAmI);
    mapView.postInvalidate(); }
```

I don't have any map related code in the `onDestroy` method. ***My question is: How can I put a `mapView` into a service so it runs even when the device is asleep and/or is there another/better way to accomplish this?***
Thanks for your time and effort!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> a service running a stopwatch so the user's device can go to sleep and what-not with out the stopwatch stopping

The stopwatch will most certainly "stop" when the device falls asleep, because the CPU powers down and your code stops running. The only way that would not occur is if you use a `WakeLock`.

That being said, you do not need to keep the device running to track time.

> This created gaps in the GPS and makes it impossible to track speed or distance

You are welcome to use `LocationManager` to get your own GPS fixes. However, "gaps in the GPS" does not make it "impossible to track speed or distance", mainly because you **always** have gaps. Whether the gaps are a millisecond or a millennium will certainly vary, but you calculate distance and speed the same way: distance is determined by comparing the locations of two GPS fixes, and speed is the distance divided by the elapsed time.

> How can I put a mapView into a service so it runs even when the device is asleep

You can't.

> and/or is there another/better way to accomplish this?

Either redesign your app to better handle the case where the device falls asleep, or do not allow the device to fall asleep (e.g., `android:keepScreenOn="true"` on your `MapView`, or a `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` in your `Service` that uses `LocationManager` to determine location).

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Guess I will the LocationManager. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the coordinates user went to, you can use [Location Manager](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/location/locationmanager.html).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to keep a mapview running in your service (not to forget the mapview that'll run in your existing activity as well) you should use a [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) and store the points visited by the user (found by using the [requestLocationUpdate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener%29) method in LocationManager) in an ArrayList or a similar data-structure and then all you have to do is use this list of points to display the places visited by the user.